# Can we detect network type using browser javascript code

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there a way to enforce browser or web page to use 3G network ( not Wi-Fi ). I don't want to use any native code, I have to do this in JavaScript code.

Comment: You can get, you cannot set

Comment: why do you want this ??

Comment: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/dap/raw-file/tip/network-api/Overview.html

Comment: Exactly, the question is why would you want to do that anyway? Using my or any available Wi-Fi usually comes at no or little extra cost – whereas being forced to use a mobile connection would could into the usually limited traffic, and is therefor highly likely to cause significant extra cost.

Comment: JavaScript running in a browser for a page runs in the client browser once a response to particular request has been served (either a static set of files or a response built up with an application). The connection is not in the same OSI layer as the connection to the internet http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model.

Comment: this is project requirement, i know its weird, but m still not getting any relevant info

Answer (score 0):

It's not so simple at the moment. The browser would have to give out that information. Firefox started recently an experimental feature which allows this via the `navigator` DOM object, but it's the only browser that supports it so far.

Check out [navigator.connection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation.connection).